# Program figuring out if a number entered is even

Tags: java

I need to make it so the computer figures out whether an int somebody entered is even or not. How would I prove that? I tied just dividing it by two, but that isn't a boolean, and I don't know how I would figure it out with booleans either. Also would I need a separate counter to count the evens?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class evenNumber {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 int numberOne = 0; 
  for(int counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++)
   System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
   numberOne = scan.nextInt(); 
  if(numberOne/2  ){

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Try the modulus operator `%`.

Comment: What is the point of answering a question like this?  Countless duplicates already exist.  It should be downvoted and closed.

Comment: I asked two questions jahroy, look and you will see the second one, it isn't a complete copy.

Comment: It is useful for me, I am trying to learn and I asked some people for help, I'm sorry I have nothing to offer when it comes to coding knowledge, also I didn't see the other post sorry.

Comment: I'm not saying this question wasn't useful to you.  You have nothing to apologize for.  I am speaking to the people who chose to answer this question rather than linking to one of the many duplicates that already exist for this question.

Answer (score 4):

use the modulo operator :

```
if (varName % 2 == 0) {
    //divisible by two
} else {
    //not
}
```

Comment: But how would I count the evens, I already am counting how many times the person is entering a number.

Comment: To count the evens, make an integer `evenCount` and every time it returns even, simply say `evenCount++;`

Comment: not sure I understand your question -- this if statement will determine if a number is even or not.

Comment: My teacher made it seem as if counter was a special type of code, I didn't know I could make variations, thanks.

Comment: `evenCount` could just be an iterating variable. Counting doesn't have to be a difficult task, just add one to the variable every time you want one to be added.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
if( number % 2 == 0){
 //it is even
}
```

`%` returns the reminder of a division and if there is no remainder(i.e it is zero) it was divisible that number. In this case if it is divisible by 2 it is even.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished through the `%` operator.  Try something like

```
if(numberOne % 2 == 0)
    //Number is even
} else {
    //Number is odd
}
```

Explanation:

The `%` operator gets the remainder of the value divided by the value. So `numberOne % 2` would either return 0 if it can be divided by 2, or 1 if it can't.

If you wanted to count the evens, declare a variable `int evenCount`, and every time `if(numberOne % 2 == 0)`, simply go `evenCount++`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(number%2 == 0)
System.out.println("even");
else
System.out.println("odd");
```

The "%" gives you the remainder after division like 3%3 =0, 4%3=1, 5%3=2, 6%3=0

Answer (score -2):

I would use bitwise and:

```
if ((number & 1) == 0) {
    // Even.
} else {
    // Odd.
}
```

This is basically checking to see if the low order bit is zero.

This is much faster than using the modulus operator (`%`).

Comment: Suggesting `%` would be better.  No need to teach a brand new programmer to optimize _super_ pre-maturely.

Comment: the % operator is better suited to this kind of operation.  It's what it was made for.